# How do you restore the values of the form in case if validation failed (in Kohana 3)

Tags: php, kohana, kohana-3

There is a sample in the bottom of the official documentation http://kohanaframework.org/3.2/guide/kohana/security/validation

But obviously it wont work at the request as long as `$post['username']` in View is used but the `$post` array is empty on first request.

So how do you restore the values in this case? Any general solution?

PS: yes, I do understand I could do `isset($post['username']) ? $post['username'] : '';` but it is just annoying

Comment: I'm not familiar with the framework, but why not store the values in a session?

Comment: @Paul: because it makes no sense - to move the data that are already in one superglobal `$_POST` to another superglobal `$_SESSION`

Comment: @zerkms Most people would probably just follow the example and ignore the notices warnings by changing the `error_reporting` settings to something like `E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE`.

Comment: @Kemal Fadillah: supressing any sort of messages (warnings and notices) always leads to difficulties in code debugging. It is much easier to just write a code that doesn't throw any sort of errors.

Comment: @zerkms - Sorry, I misunderstood your question.

Comment: @zerkms Right. I'm with you on that one. But AFAIK, Kohana doesn't really have a way of repopulating the form fields. I think there's a 3rd party library somewhere that provides the option, but I'm not sure. Your best bet would probably be creating your own function that will handle this.

Comment: @Kemal Fadillah: generally I just override `Form::input()` to restore the data from `$_POST/$_GET` but this time I was curious if there is a way "by design" to do the same things. It would be sad if there is no any :-(

Comment: @zerkms I was just looking at the old documentation http://docs.kohanaphp.com/libraries/validation#building_and_validating_a_form. You can see from the sample code that first you need to initialize an array with the form field names as the key and set the value to an empty string. And if there's an error, fill in the values of each element. In the views, you can simply call `Form::input()` normally without any `if` statement or some sort. So I guess Kohana has already been built this way from the start. And it doesn't seem to change. You'll probably just need to do the same thing.

Comment: @Kemal Fadillah: that is just terrible. Put it as an answer please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use the model to display the data in the form. That way the initial form value is the initial value in the model.

I then update the model data with POST data in the controller, if there are validation errors, the model data will contain the POST data. This means I don't have to put any conditional logic in the view, and I just do:  `Form::input('name',  $model->name)`

Here's a more detailed explanation of this approach: [Kohana ORM and Validation, having problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9123684/kohana-orm-and-validation-having-problems/9127417#9127417)

Comment: This is perfectly fine unless you have the code in your view that depends on the model values. In your case the model will have new values assigned and therefore dependent code may behave differently.

Comment: The code in my view entirely depends on the model values, that's the point and exactly how I want it, as I'm updating the model. If I have other dependant code, I would be using a different loaded model.

Comment: I mean that quite often it's necessary to split between POST and model data. Suppose you have a button that is visible only when the model `status` property is set to "open". If you want to set the `status` to "closed" but fail on validation, the button will be hidden, despite you'd like it to be visible.

Comment: Not sure I completely understand your example but I don't deny unique use cases exist. I would argue that if you're updating models it's quite rare you need to distinguish between model data and POST data.

Comment: +1 because this approach also let's you have only one action and only one view for creating a new record and editing an existent one. I name my action "edit" and it edits new or existent records, it's the same, you just do `$model = ORM::factory('model', $this->request->param('id'));` and if there's no ID in the URL, the Request::param() method returns `NULL` and ORM gives you an empty model to create a new record.

Answer (score 2):

I use [Arr::get](http://kohanaframework.org/3.2/guide/api/Arr#get) function:

```
echo Form::input('name', Arr::get($post, 'name'))
```

Answer (score 1):

I was just looking at the old documentation on [Building and Validating a Form](http://docs.kohanaphp.com/libraries/validation#building_and_validating_a_form).

You can see from the sample code that first you need to initialize an array with the form field names as the key and set the value to an empty string. And if there's an error, fill in the values of each element. In the views, you can simply call `Form::input()` normally without any `if` statement or some sort.

I guess Kohana has already been built this way from the start. And it doesn't seem to change. You'll probably just need to do the same thing.