# Which function adds data from a form to a db in Kohana

Tags: kohana

I am using Kohana version 3 and would like to modify a form input field. I am having troubles understanding how this works in kohana. Is the input done by a controller or a helper? What do Controllers and helpers actually do in Kohana?

thanks for any advice,

Rob

Comment: I think a submit is processed with an action...but where would they be defined?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally, I would use the Kohana form helpers to build the HTML tags for the form and fields, and pass data into these helper methods from the controller.

For example, in my view `views/contact.php`:

```php
<?php echo Form::open()?>
    <fieldset>

        <div class="field">
            <?php echo 
                Form::label('name', __('Name')),
                Form::input('name',  $name)
            ?>
        </div>

        <?php echo Form::submit('save', 'Save')); ?>
    </fieldset>
<?php echo Form::close()?>
```

In controller `classes/controller/contact.php`

```php
class Controller_Contact extends Controller {

        public function action_index()
        {
                $view = View::factory('contact')
                        ->set('name', 'Richard');

                $this->response->body($view);
        }
}
```

Adding that data to a table in the db is a bit more complicated, but generally you would use a model to do that. Have a read through the ORM documentation: http://kohanaframework.org/3.2/guide/orm

A controller would handle the request data and would interact with the model to save the data to the database.

Here's an example of that process: [Kohana ORM and Validation, having problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9123684/kohana-orm-and-validation-having-problems/9127417#9127417)

Have a read through the documentation to get a better understanding of these concepts: http://kohanaframework.org/3.2/guide/kohana/